# Constructing a transfer function

Tags: math, construction, transfer-function

How would I go about creating the below transfer function?

[image]

It would take two parameters:

- position of bulge in range (-1.0, +1.0)
- sharpness of bump

That picture only demonstrates movement in the first parameter.

I can think of a few possible approaches:

- figure out a formula
- Bezier curves?
- start with a few points and do some kind of chain-links type physics dynamical simulation, where each link exerts a force of its neighbours, and the end links are held low, a particular link is held high
- something like the above but starting out with a crude shape and filtering out high frequencies

However I can't see any simple way to set out on any of the above approaches.

Can anyone see a clean way to crack it?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a [normal distribution with variable skew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) to me.  I would look for something like that before I'd go for Bezier curves.